# Is train_test_split(shuffle=False) appropriate for time series?

Tags: python, time-series

Is the sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(shuffle=False) method appropriate for times series forocast? Or one should never use this method to perform the train and test set split when dealing with time series?

Many people argue that `train_test_split` should not be used because it does the split randomly, which leads to data leakeage. However, if the setting of `shuffle=False` is precisely to define that there should be no data leak between the training and test sets, why not use `train_test_split(shuffle=False)` for time series?

I know about the `TimeSeriesSplit`, but I would like to understand, still, if it is correct to use `train_test_split(shuffle=False)` for time series.

Comment: If your dataset is sorted by date/time before the split and you only need one split, then setting `shuffle=False` will get you that one non-random split. But `TimeSeriesSplit` has a minimum of two splits, so if you need multiple validation sets, use that.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do a random split when dealing with time series data as you need to maintain the continuity of the data. So instead you should use another method like `sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit`.

This will allow to create multiple folds of the data which follow the time element of your data, and keep training on older (past) data and testing (predicting) on newer (future) data.

By using `shuffle=True`, you are shuffling your data randomly, which is useful in some cases, but not when dealing with time-based data. So you should use `shuffle=False`.

An alternative would be to manually split your data, say with by taking the first 80% for train (past) and last 20% for test (future), but it is easier to use functions already written for us if they're available.

You can read more about it here: [TimeSeriesSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html).

Comment: I just updated the question, precisely to improve the point you mention. when I set `train_test_split(shuffle=False)` does it still split randomly?

Comment: @user14738548  I've updated my answer to try to clarify it. But yeah in short shuffle=False will shuffle your data, which is is not something you want with time series data.

Comment: @AdamJaamour, `shuffle=False` will NOT shuffle the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple explanation of why it's not a good idea to shuffle data when working with time series:

Imagine that you have a bunch of data points that represent things that happened over time. Each data point has a time stamp, like a date, that tells you when it happened.

Now, imagine that you mix up all of the data points and put them in a different order. This is like shuffling a deck of cards. It might seem like a good idea because it helps you check if your model is working well, but it's actually not a good idea because the order of the data points is important.

The data points are like a story, and the order they happened in is important to understanding the story. If you shuffle the data points, it's like telling the story out of order, and it doesn't make sense anymore. It's hard for your model to learn from the data if the data doesn't make sense.

So, when you're working with time series data, it's important to keep the data points in the order that they happened. This way, your model can learn from the data and make good predictions.